# Why use commas between JavaScript declarations and initializations?

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose of separating code using commas instead of moving to the next line?

For example, I found this code:

```
var fm = $.NSFileManager.defaultManager,
oURL = $.NSURL.fileURLWithPathIsDirectory(strPath, true),
lstFiles = ObjC.unwrap(
    fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtURLIncludingPropertiesForKeysOptionsError(
        oURL, [], 1 << 2, null
    )
),
lstHarvest = [];
```

I don't see it often but it feels like a run on sentence.

Update:
I think I see what is going on but I rarely ever see this. Is it ES5, ES6 thing?

Comment: It's just initializing multiple variables on one line, in one statement. Nothing to do with ES5 or 6.

Comment: `1 << 2` ? Seriously? Why not simply `4` ??

Comment: And personally i would indent the following lines so that all variable identifiers are on the same height.

Comment: Comment: All the answers are correct. Who thinks SO should let people select multiple answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comma allows the programmer to omit `var` at the beginning of each declaration/definition. It's up to your preferred style to decide which form is used but be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

This is the syntax for `var` :

> var varname1 [= value1] [, varname2 [= value2] ... [, varnameN [= valueN]]];

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

note that the presence of initializations (`=`) is irrelevant.

### Why use this syntax ?

- to avoid repeating `var`. Compare :

  ```
  var a, b, c, d, e
  ```

  or

  ```
  var a,
      b,
      c,
      d,
      e
  ```

  versus

  ```
   var a
   var b
   var c
   var d 
   var e
  ```
- sometimes a matter of style and preference
- in some places you must use this syntax to declare several variables because you can't use several lines, (e.g. in a for loop header : `for (var a = 0, b = 3; ... ; ...)`)

---

Note that this is *not* the same thing as having new lines ! (the other lines after first would not be `var` variable declarations, see [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it) for the differences).

Your example would however be equivalent without commas at the end *and* with `var` at beginning of each others.

---

> Is it ES5, ES6 thing?

It is the syntax since ECMAScript 1st edition (1997)

https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf

(page 63 / 110 of the pdf file, section 12.2, variable statement)

Answer (score 2):

There is just one `var` used for initializing multiple Variables. You can also do this (I think this is much better and more readable):

```
var fm = $.NSFileManager.defaultManager;
var oURL = $.NSURL.fileURLWithPathIsDirectory(strPath, true);
var lstFiles = ObjC.unwrap(
    fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtURLIncludingPropertiesForKeysOptionsError(
    oURL, [], 1 << 2, null));
var lstHarvest = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

Like most other languages like c,c++
we can declare

```
int a,b,c;
char x='1',y='2';
```

like this javascript also allow us to this . Simple :)